# cookie not registering

Tags: php

I have a login page that asks the users login details sends it to a cookie and then validates the details but for some reason it does  not allow me to login in. If I test it locally on abyss webserver installed on my computer it works fine but if I test it on my hosting server it does not work here is my code:

It works like this as soon as the login page is selected it asks the details what then happens then if the user is not activated it asks to activate the user the login works if the user is activated but as soon as the user is not it does not continue further than the activation request.

Login ask:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?cont=true&loginUSER=true" style="font-family:Calibri;">
<fieldset style="border-style:none">
        <p>
        Email: <input style="position:absolute; left:30%;" onkeyup="javascript: this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();" class="details" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
        Password: <input style="position:absolute; left:30%;" class="details" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn" style="background-color:#FFF;    border-style:solid; border-width:thin;  font-family:Calibri;" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The it check the login first if no cookie exists and then if one does exists

```
//A new login first create cookies and check if they are valid
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["thebillboard"]))
        {
            //Don't allow user to login if this is not true;        
            $thisIsValid = false;
            //set cookies for login details entered!
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $pass = $_POST["password"];

            setcookie("thebillboard",$email,time()+3600);
            setcookie("password",$pass,time()+3600);

            //check if the login details exists
            $clients = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clients))
            {
                if(($row["businessEmail"] == $email) && ($row["password"]) == $pass)
                {
                    $thisIsValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //If the cookies exists check if they are valid
        elseif(isset($_COOKIE["thebillboard"]))
        {
            //Don't allow user to login if this is not true;        
            $thisIsValid = false;
            //get cookies for login if it exists!
            $email = $_COOKIE["thebillboard"];
            $pass = $_COOKIE["password"];

            //check if the login details exists
            $thisIsValid = false;
            $clients = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clients))
            {
                if(($row["businessEmail"] == $email) && ($row["password"] == $pass))
                {
                    $thisIsValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

then if the variable $thisIsValid is true it continues and shows the login user else it returns error in login details

Comment: Don't store passwords in cookies

Answer (score 0):

If using Chrome you can install this add-on, it will help you see the cookies associated with the active site: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en

From here you should be able to deduce what's going wrong (if it's cookie related).

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your cookie without plugins.
At the end of your script, put a header redirection to an empty page.

```
header("Location: /debug.php");
```

There, in degub.php, just do print_r($_COOKIE) and see what is contains.

Note: i don't really care for possible wrong headers from this redirection - it's just for debug purposes, so no comments on this please.